# How to get a summary of CUDA runtime errors at the end of an application

Tags: cuda

I found that getting cuda status report for each individual piece of code (cudaMalloc, cudaMemCpy, kernel code...) is useful but boring. Is there anyway to do it a single time at the end of code (if I don't care where the error comes from)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a macro to check for an error, so there's almost no extra code to write. I've included a couple of functions below that allow you to write CUDA calls such as:

```
cudaCheck(cudaMalloc(&my_array, 10));
```

And, after calling a kernel:

```
cudaCheckLastError("MyKernel failed");
```

The advantage with this approach is that you get information about exactly what failed, and your program doesn't try to keep running. I recommend that you use this method, as it will save you lots of work in the long run.

On more of an academic note, you could probably use asynchronous CUDA calls, and then check for an error at the very end. So, for instance:

```
cudaMemcpyAsync(...);
```

And then, you can run `cudaDeviceSynchronize();` at the end, which will return the latest error that occured (if any occured).

That's really not recommended though. See chapter 3.2.8, Error Checking, in the CUDA C Programming Guide 4.2 for more information.

Macros for checking for errors. If an error has occured, these will print the error and exit the program:

.h:

```
void __cudaCheck(cudaError err, const char* file, const int line);
#define cudaCheck(err) __cudaCheck (err, __FILE__, __LINE__)

void __cudaCheckLastError(const char* errorMessage, const char* file, const int line);
#define cudaCheckLastError(msg) __cudaCheckLastError (msg, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

.cpp:

```
void __cudaCheck(cudaError err, const char *file, const int line)
{
  if( cudaSuccess != err) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s(%i) : CUDA Runtime API error %d: %s.\n",
      file, line, (int)err, cudaGetErrorString( err ) );
    exit(-1);
  }
}

void __cudaCheckLastError(const char *errorMessage, const char *file, const int line)
{
  cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
  if( cudaSuccess != err) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s(%i) : getLastCudaError() CUDA error : %s : (%d) %s.\n",
      file, line, errorMessage, (int)err, cudaGetErrorString( err ) );
    exit(-1);
  }
}
```