# cublasDgemm returns CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED

Tags: cuda, cublas

I'm using cublasDgemm to multiply two matrices.

I wrote a method that uses cublasDgemm and returns the pointer to the output.

It seems to work well in my unit tests but it fails in my application code (return code CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED).

I went over the code many times now and everything seem ok.. is there anyway to get a better error explanation?

Update: It seems like every 2nd cublasDgemm call works. The first one I'm getting this error, the second one I get success.. any ideas?

Update2: This is my call

```
    const double alpha = 1.0;

    const double beta = 0;

cublasStatus_t ret = cublasDgemm(RmCudaMatrix::handle_, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, 
    Rows(), b.Cols(), Cols(), &alpha,
    device_matrix_, Rows(), b.device_matrix_, b.Rows(), &beta,
    output->device_matrix_, output->Rows());
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are the parameters exactly the same for the first and second calls? If not, try to make them the same and see if the first call still fails while the second one succeeds.

Comment: Yes, it's the same parameters.

Comment: Are you checking for errors correctly? Maybe it's the first one that fails, but you don't receive the error until the second call because of the async nature of CUDA.

Comment: @RogerDahl - I'm currently checking only the return value of the function. Can you point me to the correct way? thanks.

Comment: In the reference I'm looking at, `cublasDgemm` returns void. I haven't used CUBLAS, but you might want to try treating the calls like CUDA kernel calls. So, use a macro like [cudaCheckLastError](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13129069/442006).

Comment: I didn't notice the description of `cublasGetError()` in the CUBLAS reference. I'm guessing you're using that to check for errors after the `cublasDgemm()` call? If so, the macros I linked should not be necessary. You may have to post a self contained example that reproduces the error for us to be able to help.

Comment: The CUDA guide (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#error-checking) says that the only way to check errors for async functions is to call cudaDeviceSyncronhize() and to check its return value. Doesn't it defeat the purpose of aysnc calls?

Comment: `cublasGetError()` is cublas legacy api, I'm using the new api where each method returns an error value. http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_CUBLAS_Users_Guide.pdf

Comment: I added `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` with error checking after every cuda call. Everything succeeds but this cublasDgemm() call.. I'll try to make a sample of this failure.

Comment: About `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`, running it after each async call would indeed defeat the purpose of the async calls. Instead, check the error return from the async call, which holds the error from the previous call, if any.

Comment: Your hunch was right, it was an error from a previous async call. I spread `cudaGetLastError()` calls in all of my code and finally I found the method that actually failed. This was really annoying. :) Please put your comment as answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CUBLAS functions may run asynchronously so, when a CUBLAS call returns a `cublasStatus_t` other that `CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS`, the error may be in a previous call. To determine if this is the case, check the CUDA error status after each CUBLAS call with `cudaGetLastError()`.